# Which method is called when tab bar presents new view controller via storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

Right now I have my `UITabBar` hooked up to `ViewController` via storyboard (relationship) so that when the app is started, `ViewController` is presented. The `UITabBar` is the initial view controller, and it immediately presents `ViewController`. I want to pass some parameters to the `ViewController` from the `UITabBar`.

I tried

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
```

but it doesn't get called. Is there a method that gets called when a `UITabBarController` presents a view controller from a storyboard relationship?

Comment: Have you tried setting the parameters on the initial view controller that's displayed? The tabBarController, in my experience, normally keeps to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the property you want to set is: `somePropertyAtFirstViewController`, then you just have to make this call in the UITabBarControllers `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[self.viewControllers firstObject]setSomePropertyAtFirstViewController:someValue];
```

Because `viewDidLoad` is called when the UITabBarController has loaded its viewControllers ...with reservation that I may have misunderstood the question.